# @WebService(wsdlLocation = not as advertised

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've seen plenty of posts about the error
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: [failed to localize] cannot.load.wsdl
but the responses all seem to deal with workarounds, such as using WEB-INF, rather than explaining why the documentation for the WebService annotation is inaccurate when it states simply that the URL string is a relative or absolute path.  Even a non-portable file:/// structure beginning at the root of the C: drive doesn't work, let alone something relative to my classpath.

Without forcing the ?wsdl query to respond with the WSDL for the parent class, it's a useless query, as it defines a specific service to a client that currently can use a local copy of the WSDL to access a standardized list of services that an individual server may or may not flesh out.  The fact that ?wsdl is a simple GET query makes it ludicrous that its response isn't more directly customizable, but I'm stuck with this poorly documented (one line, under 10 words), seemingly flaky "tool."

Please don't lecture me on your particular way of implementing your project.  I've wasted too much time on this relatively unimportant "convenience" already, and a total redesign is totally out of the question.  Thank you in advance for not cluttering the responses in this way if you don't have an answer or a simple example that works.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo SR2 Build id: 20120216-1857; the eclipse default workspace JRE system library; and a list of jars that I could include if necessary, but for now the only one that seems to have even a peripheral possibility of relevance is javax.persistence_2.0.4.201112161009.jar.  I'm also using @BindingType(value="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")
because what the client seems capable of inferring from the WSDL, the server seems clueless about, even though it too uses code generated from the same WSDL!

BTW, just in case it might have been something flaky in the Eclipse Console environment, I rebuilt the jar and copied it to a minimally configured subdirectory of a new path to isolate it, along with another classpath containing the WSDL file, and the very same error came up.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after studying GrepCode listings of the partially deprecated code that makes up the endpoint implementation, I found that maybe my classpath resource wasn't getting through, so I cast the "this" argument to the type relevant to child, for whatever reason that was necessary, and I got a new error, a CATCH-22!  It tells me that the services listed in the parent WSDL don't include the service named after the child.  Why should they?!

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSDL ... has the following services ... but not ...  Maybe you forgot to specify a serviceName and/or targetNamespace in @WebService/@WebServiceProvider?

Well, I'll try specifying the serviceName and/or the targetNamespace to see if that eliminates these unwarranted presumptions, but if that doesn't work, I've consumed a lot of time for nothing.

...

Apparently the various forms of Endpoint.publish() don't include specifying a QName that won't make these unnecessary and unwarranted assumptions.  Either that or the wsdlLocation is for internal consumption and not for publishing!

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  After tweaking name and serviceName (which seem poorly differentiated if name is the "name of the service", so I made them ithe same), adding a portName after guessing what it would be and finally using the one from the WSDL, AND setting the targetNameSpace from the WSDL, I actually got a ?wsdl response that seems to be consistent with the one I've been trying to get, with the exception that the spacing is different, and I don't see a diff option to compare multiline groups against a single line.  The only way to know for sure is to modify one of my clients to see if it chokes on the ?wsdl query URL!

Finally, just to be sure this somewhat stream-of-consciousness post comes up in a search by someone else looking in vain for something relevant to a similar issue, in case I neglected to refer to the original error, here it is:

com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: [failed to localize] cannot.load.wsdl

I hope that will justify my rambling!  (BTW, yes, it works with my client, finally!)